# Some questions regarding a proof of existence of bound states in semilinear schrödinger equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I dont quite get some steps in this proof. I would appreciate if someone could help me with them. It is from the book "Semilinear Schrödinger Equations" by Cazenave

- How is it clear that $\varphi$ is an even function?
- Why is it that integrating and taking the derivative (why is it called multplying by $\varphi$'?) leads the equation to be 0?
- How can we deduce that the decay of $\varphi$ is exponential in the end?

[image: This is the theorem]
[image: This is the proof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Eq.$(8.1.25)$ remains the same under the change of variable $x\to -x$; therefore, if $\varphi(x)$ is a solution to that equation, then $\psi(x)=\varphi(-x)$ also is. Since $\psi(0)=\varphi(0)=c$ and $\psi'(0)=-\varphi(0)=0$, it follows that $\psi(x)$ also satisfies the same initial conditions as $\varphi(x)$. If the solution to such initial value problem is unique, then $\varphi(-x)=\psi(x)=\varphi(x)$, which implies that $\varphi$ is an even function of $x$.
2. Multiplying Eq.$(8.1.25)$ (with $u=\varphi$) by $\varphi'$ and rearranging terms we obtain
   $$
   \varphi'\varphi''-\omega\varphi\varphi'+|\varphi|^{\alpha}\varphi\varphi'
   =\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\varphi'^2-\frac{\omega}{2}\varphi^2+
   \frac{1}{\alpha+2}|\varphi|^{\alpha+2} \right)=0, \tag{1}
   $$
   hence
   $$
   \frac{1}{2}\varphi'^2-\frac{\omega}{2}\varphi^2+
   \frac{1}{\alpha+2}|\varphi|^{\alpha+2}=c_1. \tag{2}
   $$
   The integration constant $c_1$ is determined by the initial conditions $\varphi(0)=c=(\omega(\alpha+2)/2)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ and $\varphi'(0)=0$:
   $$
   c_1=-\frac{\omega}{2}c^2+\frac{1}{\alpha+2}c^{\alpha+2}
   =c^2\left(-\frac{\omega}{2}+\frac{1}{\alpha+2}\frac{\omega(\alpha+2)}{2}\right)
   =0. \tag{3}
   $$
3. If follows from Eq.(8.1.25) that
   $$
   -\frac{\varphi''}{\varphi}+\omega=|\varphi|^{\alpha}\xrightarrow{x\to\infty}0, \tag{4}
   $$
   therefore $\varphi(x)\sim Ce^{-\sqrt{\omega}\,x}$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the 3. point though? Not sure I get how one sees the exponential decay?

Comment: ah cool thanks. didn't know the last part